# Microsoft Graph PowerShell access permissions - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the [Microsoft PowerShell Intune cmdlets](https://github.com/microsoft/Intune-PowerShell-SDK) to query configuration settings for audit purposes. I'm unable to connect with an account that does not have Admin access, despite using the AdminConsent to grant the application access. I've also explicitly added my user to the app and can see that "delegated" access has been granted.

I have successfully connected to my Azure environment with my administrator account using:

```
Connect-MSGraph -AdminConsent
Get-DeviceManagement_DeviceCompliancePolicies
```

When running this with another account which is not a global administrator I receive the error:

```
Get-DeviceManagement_DeviceCompliancePolicies : 401 Unauthorized
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"ErrorCode\":\"Forbidden\",\"Message\":\"{\\r\\n \\\"_version\\\": 3,\\r\\n  \\\"Message\\\": 
\\\"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 6407b0fa-a2fd-4564-8895-cc63b49e2201
```

I can see, however, that my user has the expected delegate access including:

```
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Perform user-impacting remote actions on Microsoft Intune devices |
| ------------------------------ | --------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Read and write Microsoft Intune devices                           |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Read and write Microsoft Intune RBAC settings                     |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Read and write Microsoft Intune apps                              |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Read and write Microsoft Intune Device Configuration and Policies |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Read and write Microsoft Intune configuration                     |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Read and write all groups                                         |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Read directory data                                               |
| Microsoft Graph                | Delegated | Sign users in                                                     |
| Windows Azure Active Directory | Delegated | Sign in and read user profile                                     |
| Windows Azure Active Directory | Delegated | Read all groups                                                   |
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/developer/intune-graph-apis) is less than helpful, despite referencing the specific error I'm getting ("Your tenant credentials support administrative functions."). It is unclear whether it's even possible to use a read-only account to gather data.

Comment: You should only be calling `Connect-MSGraph -AdminConsent` _once_ per tenant. To call the API you should be using `Connect-MSGraph` (i.e. without the `AdminConsent`).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - thanks - to be clear, I have indeed ran this once with the adminconsent (in order to allow the app) and subsequent calls have ran without this- unfortunately that doesn't resolve my issue though. I suspect this might actually be an issue elsewhere with my access rights to Azure Intune - but it's hard to see where given the delegated access noted

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot grant permissions through Graph that are more expansive than what that User could do on their own. So if your user can't manage Intune, it also won't be able to use Graph/PowerShell to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't being patient enough - it took 24 hours for the permissions to "kick in".

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem and the time delay was not the issue.

In our case, the root cause was that the service account (User object) we were using was not granted the "Intune Administrator" role in Azure AD, which is a prerequisite mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/intune-graph-samples/

Once we added that role, our Intune cmdlets started working straight away.